# How to generate a randomized range of numbers that sums into end parameter

Tags: excel, random

I have a spreadsheet with a certain parameters:
Range start: 1
Range end: 100
Randomization: N

Then there is a list with a size of 5.
Excel generates me numbers with a step of 20 in each cell of that list.
And if list size is changed, the step size will also change accordingly

I am trying to randomize every entry by +- of N so that an end sum would still be 100.
Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: Can you create some visualization to go along with your question?

Comment: This is unclear. My interpretation is: you have a list of numbers and you are trying to randomly perturb the numbers (with perturbations in the range `[-N,N]`) so that the sum of the list is unchanged. If so, this is still unclear. Are the perturbations integer values (suggested by your use of the symbol `N`) or are they decimal numbers? What probability distribution are you trying to enforce? If you want it uniform subject to the constraints, VBA would probably be required. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, canonical way to sample such random number is to apply [Multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution). It is automatically makes sum equal to desired number.

In your case, n = 100, k = 5, p<sub>i</sub> = 1/5 = 0.2. I know Excel provides function **MULTINOMIAL(x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>k</sub>)** = n!/(x<sub>1</sub>!*...*x<sub>k</sub>!) so probabilities could be computed with easy (see http://www.real-statistics.com/binomial-and-related-distributions/multinomial-distribution/). I don't know how to do sampling in Excel, perhaps stats package for Excel has desired functionality.

UPDATE

There is Excel sampling code right in the wiki page on multinomial, but I think it would be slow